# Error al instalar gema de mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Actualmente estoy intentando instalar la gema de mysql en lugar de sqlite, que es la gema que viene por defecto, para usar mysql con xampp en windows 10 pero me da un error que no he conseguido solucionar.

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use mysql2 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
```

Cuando ejecuto el comando bundle install es cuando me da el error, dejo captura de pantalla con el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No he dado con una solución a esto a si que probé a utilizar postgresql junto con pgadmin y la gema postgresql y funciono todo a la primera

Answer (score 0):

Te sale `you have to install development tools first`, significa que solo tienes instalado ruby, sin librerías de desarrollo para compilar ciertas gemas que necesitan extensiones nativas de tu sistema operativo.
Nunca he trabajado con ruby en Windows, de hecho ni idea cual sea la forma "estándar" de instalar ruby, pero con [Ruby Installer](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) deberías elegir e instalar una de las versiones que dicen "with devkit".